# In CHANGE DATA CAPTURE (CDC) how can capture timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, database-administration

In CDC technique how can we load data for time is inserted, deleted, updated. Is there any way we can capture these from CDC tables into data warehouse table?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one of the columns in the change tables is lsn. That's the log sequence number. You can map it to when it happened by using the function sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-cdc-map-lsn-to-time-transact-sql

Comment: is there any way we can store this data . such as if anyone performs and INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE on any of our tables, we would like to see a timestamp, user id, table/column identifying information, and information detailing the change(s) they made. For INSERTs and DELETEs, we would like to see what data was inserted/deleted. For UPDATEs, we would like to see the old and new values.